# remove other wording other than the normal english alphabets

Tags: r

I have a set of tweets data that I believe it contains some language other than English, such as Thai and they were written in symbol such as "â", "ã", "Ø", etc  . How can I remove those wording other than the normal alphabets?

```
structure(list(text = structure(c(4L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("ãããæããããéãããæãããInappropriate announce", 
"@AirAsia your direct debit (Maybank) payment gateways is not working. Is it something you are working to fix?", 
"Bulls â äè æèäååééäéåèååäæäåççæäæææåãTravel sixtyãåääçæç ïçäèåéè #MH çæäæääéæã", 
"RT @AirAsia: ØØÙØÙÙÙÙ ÙØØØ ØØØÙ ÙØØØØÙ ØØØØÙÙÙí í Now you can enjoy a #great breakfast onboard with our new breakfast meals! http://t.co/957ZaLjYâ€¦", 
"xdek ke flight @AirAsia Malaysia to LA... hahah..bagi la promo murah2 sikit, kompom aku beli...", 
"You know there is a problem when customer service asks you to wait for 103 minutes and your no is 42 in the queue. #AirAsia"
), class = "factor"), created = structure(c(5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
1L), .Label = c("1/2/2014 16:14", "1/2/2014 17:00", "3/2/2014 0:54", 
"3/2/2014 0:58", "3/2/2014 1:28"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("text", 
"created"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for the most part:

```
gsub("[^a-zA-Z0-9 [:punct:]]","",dat$text)
```

> [1] "RT @AirAsia:       Now you can enjoy a #great breakfast onboard
>   with our new breakfast meals! http://t.co/957ZaLjY¦"
>   [2] "You know there is a problem when customer service asks you to wait for 103
>   minutes and your no is 42 in the queue. #AirAsia"
>   [3] "Inappropriate announce"
>   [4] "@AirAsia your direct debit (Maybank) payment gateways is not
>   working. Is it something you are working to fix?"
>   [5] "xdek ke flight @AirAsia Malaysia to LA... hahah..bagi la promo murah2
>   sikit, kompom aku beli..."
>   [6] "Bulls Travel sixty  #MH "